# Pandas dataframe rendering as table in Jupyter

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

If I have a `pandas.DataFrame` `df`, simply doing

```
df
```

in an empty Jupyter notebook cell will render it nicely as a table.

Having a class wrapping around a dataframe, how can I render the underlying dataframe in the same way?

```
class Wrapper:
  def __init__(self, df):
    self._df = df

  def __repr__(self):
    ## to_html does not work
    return self._df.to_html()
```

This gives the idea, but `to_html` does not seem to be able to do the trick. What could I do?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use `__repr__` for this? Can't you simply create an instance of the `Wrapper` class and call the `.df` property to return the dataframe?

Comment: I could of course do that, but as a notebook friendly syntactic sugar I'd like to do it that way as well.

Comment: You're going to run into issues using `__repr__` since it is designed to return a printable representation of the object, not a printable representation of a property of that object. Attempting to use anything other than a string for `__repr__` will throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you are looking to print the `df` as a table when a wrapper object is called? If this is the case, then you could wrap the dataframe's `_repr_html_` method.

```
class Wrapper:
    def __init__(self, df):
        self._df = df

    def _repr_html_(self):
        return self._df._repr_html_()
```

Or alternatively:

```
class Wrapper:
    def __init__(self, df):
        self._df = df

    self.repr_html = self._df._repr_html_
```

After creating your object with:

```
mytable = Wrapper(df)
```

You can display `df` in your notebook as a table by calling `mytable`

```
mytable # displays the df
```